# How can I modify this code?

Tags: python

```
from itertools import product
for d in product(range(10), repeat=4):
   if 7 in d :
      print(d)
```

This is supposed to print all numbers that have number 7, but what if I want the number that contains exactly one 7?

Comment: count the 7s you find and check if amount == 1 ?

Comment: how can check the amount

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-to-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach:

for each `d` count the number of `7s`, and select the ones that contain exactly one. (thanks @MrXcoder for the assist in the comments)

```
from itertools import product 
for d in product(range(10), repeat=4):
    if d.count(7) == 1:
        print(d)
```

Comment: Isn't this overly complicated when you could just do `if d.count(7) == 1`?